# Php: Group the first 6 characters into 3 divided by a dash

Tags: php, regex

I would like to format a number that takes the first 6 digits and group them into 3 separated by a dash '432-243-23243'. How can I allow the last digits to have any length.

`preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1,13})$/", "$1-$2-$3", $number);`

I have tried using substr `implode("-", str_split($num, 3));` but I got this result 000-000-000-0

I would like the number to be like "000-000-000000"

Comment: You need to replace the limiting quantifier with `+`: `preg_replace('/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/', "$1-$2-$3", $number);` = `+`  will match 1+ occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well:

```
<?php
$number = "123456789123";
$num = preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/", "$1-$2-$3", $number);
echo $num; // 123-456-789123
?>
```

Comment: You didn't answer his question though (How can I allow the last digits to have any length). To the OP, just change the 3rd group into (\d+) to target 1 or more numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer string functions over REGEX, if it can get the job done...

```
$str = '00000000000000000';
$repl = implode('-', str_split(substr($str, 0, 6), 3)) . '-';
echo substr_replace($str, $repl, 0, 6);

//  result: 000-000-00000000000
```

Alternatively:

```
$repl = str_pad(substr($str, 3, 3), 5, '-', STR_PAD_BOTH);
echo substr_replace($str, $repl, 3, 5);
```

Alternatively:

```
echo substr_replace($str, $str[0].$str[1].$str[2].'-'.$str[3].$str[4].$str[5].'-', 0, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) limit parameter *(if you already know that the string only contains digits and at least seven)*:

```
$str = preg_replace('~...\K~', '-', $str, 2);
```